# csvHelper switch to another columnName if column null

Tags: c#, csvhelper

```
Map(m => m.Invoice_Amount).Name("Invoice Amount");
```

Currently I am picking up the invoice Amount through the above mapping.
Is there a way when mapping to detect if a mapped field is null and then switch it to another column for instance "Invoice Due Amount"?

```
        public InvoiceMap()
    {

        Map(m => m.Invoice_Number).Name("Invoice Number");
        Map(m => m.Hierarchy_Invoice_Number).Name("Hierarchy Invoice Number");
        Map(m => m.Account_Number).Name("Account Number");
        Map(m => m.Invoice_Amount).Name("Invoice Amount");
        Map(m => m.Hierarchy_Account_Number).Name("Hierarchy Account Number");
    }
```

This is my mapping for the csvHelper.

For example what I am trying to do would be:

```
if(Map(m => m.Hierarchy_Account_Number).Name("Hierarchy Account Number") ==  null){
//if the Hierarchy account is null then use the below Invoice_Amount
    Map(m => m.Invoice_Amount).Name("Invoice Due Amount");

}else{
//Otherwise use this mapping
    Map(m => m.Invoice_Amount).Name("Invoice Amount");
}
```

Comment: can you expand your code block to show more about what youre doing. What youre asking should be possible but I need a little more context

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Hi. Please see above what I have edited.

Comment: with that if statement, have you tried that and if so, what was the error message

Comment: Yes. There is no error. The item is just mapped to the original column

Comment: In terms of a [mcve] it would be optimal if I could copy and paste your sample code into a console app and run it. It should have sample inputs built in, and expected outputs specified.

Comment: when doing your if check for `Map(m => m.Hierarchy_Account_Number).Name("Hierarchy Account Number") ==  null`, whats the value of `Map(m => m.Hierarchy_Account_Number).Name("Hierarchy Account Number")`